# Local deployment of an application in Node + React

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express, server, cors

I'm developing my application in JS, where I built the backend in Node + Express + Cors and my frontend in react. I would like to know how I can "deploy" my application on a local server (with the Windows 10 server operating system), as I want any computer that does this to be able to: [Server IP]:[Application Port]/home access and use this application.

How can I do this, do I need to do: `npm build` and configure it in the back, do I need to change something in the front? Well, I only think talking about Heroku, but I can't put it there, as my server is closed to the internet and needs to be local... (Currently the back is running on port 3333 and the front on port 3000, it would cost me to put both on port 3333 if possible)

MY APPLICATION FOLDER:

- Backend (src, package.json, package-lock.json)
- Frontend(public, src, package.json, package-lock.json)
- package.json
- package-lock.json

I studied the possible scenarios, but I always came across Heroku, but I can't use it